# I want to know a Contract address verified or not by programatically

Tags: web3js, javascript, evm, stack

I am having Token Names , Token Symbols and token addresses , I want to know that a Particular Contract address is verified or not by programmatically , but I don't want to use BSCSCAN API endpoint , is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Contract "verification" is not a blockchain concept. It's just a concept invented by blockchain explorers - there is no 'universal' verification, it's always per-service.

Verification submits the contract source code to the explorer. So if you want to know whether a contract is verified in BSCScan, you have to ask the BSCScan API. But if you want to know whether it's verified in some other blockchain explorer, you have to query that explorer's API.